Why is it suitable to use $s= \frac{1}{2}at^2$ in this situation?
Question: A car slows down uniformly on a straight road, and come to rest in 3 m . What is the ratio of the time it takes to travel each of these three metres?

So this may be quite a simple question but I am confused by what the equations mean physically.
The answer key states that the remaining distance is $s = \frac{1}{2}at^2$, but I am just wondering why it is not $s = ut-\frac{1}{2}at^2$.
How does the ut equal $2*\frac{1}{2}at^2$ ?

Edit: I actually know why it is $\frac{1}{2}at^2$ since you can find that if you calculate the area of the graph... $\frac{1}{2}(v−0)∗t$
, so $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$
However, is there an instinctive way to understand this problem?
Maybe deceleration is the same as acceleration in the sense that work done is the same (we have to move it the same distance), hence we get the same formula? (Since when you accelerate something from rest u is 0, hence $s= \frac{1}{2}at^2$)? Is this analysis correct? Thank you!

Dear close voters. Please read the Fine question. The OP is not asking us to do or check their calculation. KongMing clearly wants to understand why it's valid to use $s=\frac12 at^2$ here.

Welcome! Please don't make your post look like a revision history. You post should ask the question. To indicate that the problem has been solved, just "accept" an answer below (as you've currently done already). Folks who are interested in previous versions of your question can click the "edited X hours ago" link at the bottom to see previous versions.

If you look at the travel backwards, you'll see it. You basically got it in your remarks. As the car comes to a stop $V_f=0$. So with uniform acceleration starting from 0 to its initial speed you get $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ . Only need to remember to also reverse the times -the time for the first meter is the fastest.
That's why it says "The remaining distance" rather than the traveled distance as it would normally be.


but I am just wondering why it is not $s = ut-\frac{1}{2}at^2$. How
does the ut equal $2*\frac{1}{2}at^2$ ?

It is OK to use $s = ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ as this is a universal equation.
From the equation of motion for velocity $ v = u + at$ where v is the final velocity and in our scenario, the final velocity is zero so $ u = -at$.
This means $ut = - at^2$,
demonstrating that ut does indeed equal $2*\frac{1}{2}at^2$, when we reverse the sign to allow for the negative acceleration, yielding $s = \frac{1}{2}at^2$
You can of course reverse everything as described by Rich in his answer so that that initial velocity is zero, but you have to careful with the signs when calculating the times.

Your initial observation that
$$ut=2\cdot \frac{1}{2} a t^2$$
was correct, because if $u$ is the initial velocity and it should come to rest after time $t$ you have also
$$u=at$$
so
$$ut=a t^2$$
